# HERE API rate limit header explanation

Tags: here-api

I am using the route matching HERE api.

At some point due to the large number of requests I receive a 429 error with the following headers.

```
X-Ratelimit-Limit:[250, 250;w=10] 
X-Ratelimit-Reset:[6]
Retry-After:[6]
```

These are the only rate limiting related headers I receive.

I would like an explanation of the `X-Ratelimit-Limit:[250, 250;w=10]` header.
What does the `250` and `w=10` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number is the number of requests that you have made for the given API in the time frame.

The second section refers to the quota policy.

An example policy of 100 quota-units per minute.
100;window=60

For the current example it specifies 250 requests every 10 seconds

More details at : [RFC for rate limit header](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-polli-ratelimit-headers-00.html#rfc.section.3.1)